# MySQL UPDATE Syntax Error after 1 Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is the Query:

```
UPDATE clubs WHERE clubId = $clubId SET (name='$name', category = '$category', 'description' = '$description', president = '$president', email = '$email', phone = $phone', treasurer = $treasurer', treasurerEmail = $treasurerEmail',treasurerPhone = $treasurerPhone', advisor = '$advisor', advisorEmail = '$advisorEmail', projectCode = '$projectCode', rollover = $rollover)"
```

And I get this error when i try and run it:
Error occured while updating club."}You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE clubId = 1 SET (name='Radio', category = 'Media', 'descri' at line 1

Any ideas?

Comment: WHERE clause comes ___after___ the list of SET values (and you don't need the brackets around your SET column names/values)

Comment: SQL doesn't but it should have WHERE before SET. Leaving out the WHERE clause accidentally is destructive, but it wouldn't be if it just returned a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
UPDATE clubs SET name = '$name', category = '$category', description = '$description', president = '$president', email = '$email', phone = '$phone', treasurer = '$treasurer', treasurerEmail = '$treasurerEmail', treasurerPhone = '$treasurerPhone', advisor = '$advisor', advisorEmail = '$advisorEmail', projectCode = '$projectCode', rollover = '$rollover' WHERE clubId = '$clubId'
```

you also had a bunch of `'` out of place.

Edited the sql just for popnoodles.

```
UPDATE clubs SET
name = '$name',
category = '$category',
description = '$description',
president = '$president',
email = '$email',
phone = '$phone',
treasurer = '$treasurer',
treasurerEmail = '$treasurerEmail',
treasurerPhone = '$treasurerPhone',
advisor = '$advisor',
advisorEmail = '$advisorEmail',
projectCode = '$projectCode',
rollover = '$rollover'
WHERE clubId = '$clubId'
```

Comment: Why u no line break for readability?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `WHERE` at the end of the statement

```
UPDATE clubs SET name='$name', category = '$category', 'description' = '$description', president = '$president', email = '$email', phone = $phone', treasurer = $treasurer', treasurerEmail = $treasurerEmail',treasurerPhone = $treasurerPhone', advisor = '$advisor', advisorEmail = '$advisorEmail', projectCode = '$projectCode', rollover = $rollover WHERE clubId = $clubId
```